# Get distance after path distance allocation

Tags: arcgis-10.1, distance, linear-referencing, route, cost-path

I use ArcGIS 10.1 in Windows XP.

I have a two point feature data sets One containing a single point P1 and another containing multiple points Pm. I computed the minimum-distance path from P1 to each of the points from Pm using path distance (I have also cost and elevation rasters).

This first step worked fine, and I got an output raster Path_rast containing the paths of interest. However, I would like to know the *length in km* of each of these paths and I can't seem to find a solution for this.
I tried converting the raster to polyline and use linear referencing tools but I can't find any tool to compute the distances I am looking for.
Any suggestions?

Comment: Why didn't the raster to polyline tool work? That should have created a polyline featureclass from which you could get the polyline length. Not sure why you need to do anything with linear referencing?